# Transcribing and translating Civil Guard document from Spain

Tags: palaeography, spain

I am trying to work my way through a Civil Guard document I received from Spain for my Great Grandfather. It documents records for his service in the Civil Guard.

I tried to transcript this section:

Spanish:

> con fecha  26 de diciembre del ano anterior le fue? concerdido a este individuo 25 ? de permiso paro ? y osuna (sevilla), de los cuates ? hiro usopor haber inonefestado 120
> de convension. cumpliendo su compromiso en 3 de agosto de 1930 solicito y le fue concedido pon suprimier tele otro por el tiempo de 4 anos por reunin las condiciones prevenidas incluso la de utilidad y como comprendido en la R.O. L del 1 de agosto de 1920 (? no. 195) pero enconcepto le provisional hastra
> la aprobacion sefinitiva del excmo sr. director gradel cuerto compromiso la principio en 1 de sepbre de 1930 y lo terminara en 31 de agosto de 1934, disfruttando durante el mismo el premio menual de
> 2750 ptas. ten prueba de su conformidad firma el interesado la presente y testigo que sus eribeu = eliuteresado = miguel torres jimenez = testigos el gua d. francisco castellano caballero - el gua 1 juan mora trigo = el comondante mayor emilio bararbas selasco = rubricados.
> es copia
> el comondante mayor

English:

> on 26 december of the previous year this individual was granted 25 ? of leave for unemployment ? and osuna (sevilla), of which ? hiro usopor haber inonefestado 120
> fulfilling his commitment on 3 August 1930 he applied for and was granted a 4 year leave for the period of 4 years as he met the conditions laid down, including that of usefulness and as included in the R.O. L of 1 August 1920 (? no. 195) but he was provisionally suspended until the final approval of the R.O. L of 1 August 1920 (? no. 195) but he was not granted this leave for the period of 4 years.
> la aprobacion sefinitiva del excmo sr. director gradel gradel compromiso la principio en 1 de sepbre de 1930 y lo terminara en 31 de agosto de 1934, disfrutando durante el mismo el premio menual de
> 2750 ptas. in proof of his agreement, the interested party signs the present and witness that his eribeu = eliuteresado = miguel torres jimenez = witnesses el gua d. francisco castellano caballero - el gua 1 juan mora trigo = el comondante mayor emilio bararbas selasco = rubricados.
> is copy
> el comondante mayor

I know it is clearly not right. This is the original text:

[image]

I have been using DeepL to obtain the final translation in English.

Comment: What sort of document is it? What research have you done into the structure/likely contents of similar documents? Without context, you will always find such translations harder than they need be, whereas if you know what information is often found in such documents, you can often understand an individual document better.

Comment: @ColeValleyGirl I received it from the Civil Guard in Spain. It is my Great Grandfathers documented records for his service in the Civil Guard.

Comment: Please include that information in the question, with the 'official' document title as well, so others wil lknow what you're looking at.  What research have you done into the structure of such service records?

Comment: No idea I am afraid. I am doing this for fun and it is because they are family. I was just happy to get this far as it was a process to obtain this document. I have already done bits of it. It is just a case of reading the Spanish handwriting.

Comment: The transcript into Spanish is not very accurate. I managed to get most of it:
_Con fecha 26 de diciembre del año anterior, le fueron concedidos a este individuo 25 días de permiso para Cádiz y Osuna (Sevilla), de los cuales no hizo uso por haber manifestado XXconvenion. Cumpliendo su compromiso en 3 de agosto de 1930 solicito y le fue concedido por su primer jefe otro por el tiempo de 4 años por reunir las condiciones prevenidas, incluso la de utilidad y como comprenXX dicho en la R. O. C. de 11 de agosto de 1920 C XXX n.º 195, pero en concepto de provisional hasta la aprobación..._

Comment: _definitiva del Excmo S. Director Gral del Cuerpo. Dicho compromiso da principio en 1º de Sepbre [Septiembre] de 1930 y lo terminará en 31 de agosto de 1934, disfrutando durante el mismo el premio mensual de 275 ptas [pesetas]. Ten prueba de su conformidad firma el interesado la presente y testigo que suscriben = El interesado = Miguel Torres Jiménez, Testigo = XX ....._

Comment: You may get help on this part in [spanish.se] using the tag [identificación-de-término](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identificación-de-término).

Comment: @fedorqui FYI https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/39375/transcribing-spanish-text-from-civil-guard-records

Comment: If this is purely a Spanish translation question it doesn't fit well here especially as you've now asked it on another site and by your own admission you're not interested in learning more about the source. I wish you'd flagged it for migration to keep all the comments in one place.

Comment: @ColeValleyGirl I have not used migration before and did not think of it. Sorry.. I simply followed the advice in the comments. And I am not sure what what you mean about not being interested about the source? I myself contacted the civil guard in Madrid because I knew my great grandad worked in civil guard in Seville. They asked me to fill in a certain form from their site and in turn I received a scanned document. So I am not sure what you mean about source. The other two answers have been informative with links to additional info.

Comment: By not being interested in the source, I meant that you weren't willing to put in some (any?) effort to understand what the document was (or even what it was called, so that people trying to help you didn't have to do even the basic investigation for you) and what it might contain -- all of which is part and parcel of genealogy. You said you were only interested in getting it transcribed and translated.

Comment: Which (I'll repeat myself) would be easier if you thought about the document and its origins. For example, the Guardia Civil is a military organisation, so you might expect to find records of periods of leave granted. Knowing that would make '25 ? de permiso' easier to read as '25 diaz de permiso' or '25 days of leave.'  If you attempt to transcribe something blind, even if it's in English, it's much harder than doing it with some expectations of what the document might contain.

Comment: @ColeCalleyGirl. I see where you are coming from. Fair enough. But yes, at the end of the day I am trying to learn about my Great Granddad. Points noted. Perhaps you overlook my excitement at getting this document in the first place. But it doesn’t matter. I hear you loud and clear.

Comment: We've all been there -- been excited about a document we've just laid our hands on. And people answering questions on this site really want to help others -- but you'll get the best out of us if you help us help you.  I'm glad you've found Spanish.Stackexchange to help with transcription and translation, but please keep asking your genealogy questions here as well.

Comment: @ColeValleyGirl For sure. I still have many "brick walls" in my tree. And also, perhaps once this document is done I may have some questions suitable for here about the document.

Answer (score 1):

Document translation:
On December 26 of the previous year, this individual was granted 25 days of leave for Cadis and Osuna (Seville), which he did not use due to having made 120 lengthy [campaigns?]. Fulfilling his commitment on August 3, 1930, he requested and was granted by his first boss another one for a period of 4 years for meeting the conditions provided, including that of utility and as included in the R.O.C of August 1, 1920 (C.A no. 195) but provisionally until the final approval of the former Mr. (Mr.) Director General. Said commitment begins on September 1, 1930 and will end on August 31, 1934, enjoying during the same the monthly prize [salary?] of 2750 pesos. General proof of his agreement, the interested party signs this document and the undersigned witness = the interested party = Miguel Torres Jimenez = witnesses = the guide Mr. Francisco Castellano Caballero = the guide 1 = Juan Mora Trigo = the commander-in-chief Emilio Bararbas Velasco = initialed. It is a copy of the major commander.

Answer (score 1):

For the benefit of others, I include the translation that we actually settled on for this specific question, as it is slightly different from the answer kindly provided by @jmcglot.

English:

> 1930: On 26th December of the previous year, this individual was
> granted 25 days leave for Cadiz and Osuna (Seville), which he did not
> make use of as he stated that it was not convenient for him.
> Fulfilling his commitment on 31 August 1930, he requested and was
> granted by his first commanding officer, another 4-year period for
> fulfilling the conditions foreseen, including that of usefulness and
> as included in the R.O.C. [transcriber's note: Royal Circular Order?]
> of 11 August 1920 (C.L no. 195), but on a provisional basis until the
> final approval of the Director General of the Corps [n. of the t.:
> Excelentísmo Señor Director General del Cuerpo]. This engagement began
> on 1 September 1930 and will end on 31 August 1934, during which time
> he will receive a monthly bonus of 27.50 ptas. [pesetas]. And in proof
> of his agreement, the interested party signs the present and the
> undersigned witnesses: The interested party, Miguel Torres Jiménez.
> Witnesses: The Gua [guard?] 2nd Francisco Castellano Caballero. Gua 1o
> Juan Mora Trigo. The Major Commander Emilio Barailar Velasco.
> Rubricados [with seal, signed].
>
> This is a copy
> The Major Commander

---

Related discussion:

https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39375/28260